# XPATH for retrieving element

Tags: web-services, xslt, soap, xpath

I have this wsdl

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://testwork/" name="HelloWorldService"
             xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
             xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
             xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:tns="http://testwork/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://soapServlet/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8085/testwork/soapServlet?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="sayHelloWorldFrom">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHelloWorldFrom"/>
    </message>
    <message name="sayHelloWorldFromResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHelloWorldFromResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="additionalFault">
        <wsdl:part name="error" element="tns:responseFault"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="HelloWorld">
        <operation name="sayHelloWorldFrom">
            <input wsam:Action="http://testwork/HelloWorld/sayHelloWorldFromRequest" message="tns:sayHelloWorldFrom"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://testwork/HelloWorld/sayHelloWorldFromResponse" message="tns:sayHelloWorldFromResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="error" message="additionalFault"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="HelloWorldPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorld">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="sayHelloWorldFrom">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="error">
                <soap:fault name="error" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="HelloWorldService">
        <port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8085/testwork/soapServlet"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I want to check if this element "sayHelloWorldFrom" really exists in this schema. I use XPath for searching, this is my snippet of code

```
InputStream isr = IOUtils.toInputStream(wsdl);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        try {
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(isr);
            XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = xFactory.newXPath();
            org.w3c.dom.Element element = (org.w3c.dom.Element) xPath.compile(
                        "definitions/portType/operation[@name='" + funcName +
                        "']").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            log.info("element " + element);
            if (element == null) {
                throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.SOAP_EXCEPTION_005);
            }
```

But the element == null for some reason, but I saw via debug that funcName is really sayHelloWorldFrom. Thus what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I removed this part:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
```

xpath worked (maybe because xmlns means something for xml or xpath)

```
definitions/portType/operation[@name='sayHelloWorldFrom']
```

you can check it here http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/2403e210-fac4-4dd2-be63-69fcba8e0ac1

Comment: Thank you, but if I remove this line, my wsdl will become invalid, so what can I do to make this XPath work without removing this line?

Comment: maybe you can change to xmlns:wsdl (just guess as I am not good at that)

Comment: as I found here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp you can change it to some name.

Comment: I just now noticed that you have same namespaces : xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"